# How to call another component method in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angular1.6

I am using Angular 1.5. I have two components. I wanted to call child component method from parent component view.

```
<main-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <div ng-if="childComponentMethod()"></div>
<main-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service to share this method if you need it in different controller or you should declare it in the parent because children can have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `childComponentMethod` method lives in `child-component` scope, so it is not available outside of it. And what's more, you should not need it. If you do, it means the method should not be in the `child-component` scope in the first place.

If you need that method only here, just move it to the `main-component` scope. Otherwise, create a service and move the method there. You can then inject the service where it is needed.